# Can't trace Request Payload in Azure Logic Apps Standard

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I am working on Logic Apps Standard and adding some properties to trace the payload in Log Analytics. The workflow has many Http calls with different request payloads and I want to log the payload, so that it can be traced in case of a failure.

[image]

Using the following code under TrackedProperties:

@{Body('HTTP-ActionName')}

but this code only displays the response that is coming back, whether it's an error or a successful response.

If I use @{triggerBody()} or @{triggerOutputs()}, it displays the original payload that is being passed as a request in the main workflow.

**What I need is**, to trace the request payload that is passed under the current HTTP call (not the whole payload) along with the response that is coming.

Please note that combining @{Body('HTTP-ActionName')} with @{triggerBody()} doesn't work as @{triggerBody()} shows the main request only that is being passed.

Comment: If you want the Body(Input) of HTTP Call in next action, that is not possible, You can give output of it not the input

Answer (score 0):

> **What I need is**, to trace the request payload that is passed under the current HTTP call (not the whole payload) along with the response that is coming.

No, this is not possible as you want Body(Input) of HTTP Call in next action, that is not possible, You can give output of it(http action output) not the input to next action.

Only possible output or dynamic actions that can be used are :

[image]

But, there is a way by using Parallel branch, when you provide input to http, then and there you need to create a parallel branch with a compose or variable( the value of its is the input payload of http) like below:

[image]

So, whenever you want to trace later you can use the variable or Compose action. So the only way is storing the value of payload before itself and then you can use it.